# Bridging VLAN and Wifi

Tags: bridge, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge, bridge-router

I am in the process of building my own Linux-based router and have ran into an issue bridging the wifi and LAN networks. The box previously ran pfSense, but due to it's inability to use my internal wifi adapter, I decided to build my own router on top of CentOS 7.

The box only has one ethernet port, so I setup a managed switch to create two VLANs:

- enp3s0.10: LAN
- enp3s0.99: WAN

I setup hostapd, connected to the wifi access point, but noticed my device was unable to pull an IP from my DHCP server. The wifi devices connected to my network will need to be able to access other devices on the wired LAN, like my DHCP and DNS services.

I have tried bridging enp3s0.10 with the wifi adapter (wls4), but that only lead to my LAN port becoming inaccessible externally. Is it possible to bridge a VLAN with a wireless adapter, or is there a better way to accomplish this? How do the inexpensive consumer routers accomplish this?

**Network Topology**

As requested (thanks Damiano Verzulli), I have added a diagram of my network topology. Due to me having less than 10 reputation points, I was forced to provide a link.

[Network Topology Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBRMA.png)

**Notes:**

- The router Linux box ("Router" in the diagram) has one ethernet port (enp3s0) and an internal wifi adapter (wls4)
- With the exception of enp3s0.99 (which receives it's address/subnet from my cable modem), all other devices on my LAN have an address in the 192.168.1.0/24 space

Comment: sophos utm is a free router appliance for home usage, it work well, it got all enteprise feature

Comment: thanks, but i am more interested in learning how to make this work.

Comment: Please, can you detail your network topology? Eg: how is your AP connected to your LAN? Is it really acting as a dumb-AP and not as a wifi router? Which device is acting as the DHCP server? Which IP subnet/addresses are you using on your interfaces/devices? Also, a draft-schema (even an hand-made one attached as an image) of the whole network would be useful.

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli I have added a network topology diagram.This is my first attempt at creating one, so if I am missing anything, please let me know so I can update it. My AP is created via the service **hostapd** running on the same box, and points to the internal wifi adapter (wls4). With the exception of enp3s0.99 (gets IP/subnet from cable modem), all devices on my lan belong to 192.168.1.0/24.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue, and wanted to share with others who may face a similar problem in the future.

### My network

- **enp3s0 -** Physical ethernet adapter
- **enp3s0.10 -** VLAN; connects to LAN
- **enp3s0.99 -** VLAN; connects to WAN (cable modem)
- **wls4 -** Wireless adapter

### Solution

1. Define each network interface (including a bridge interface named **br0**)

   Set the value of **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp3s0** to:

   ```
   TYPE=Ethernet
   BOOTPROTO=none
   DEVICE=enp3s0
   ONBOOT=yes
   ```

   Set the value of **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0** to:

   ```
   DEVICE=br0
   TYPE=Bridge
   IPADDR=192.168.1.1
   NETMASK=255.255.255.0
   ONBOOT=yes
   BOOTPROTO=none
   ```

   Set the value of **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp3s0.10** to:

   ```
   DEVICE=enp3s0.10
   BOOTPROTO=none
   ONBOOT=yes
   BRIDGE=br0
   VLAN=yes
   ```

   Set the value of **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp3s0.99** to:

   ```
   DEVICE=enp3s0.99
   BOOTPROTO=dhcp
   ONBOOT=yes
   VLAN=Yes
   ```
2. Restart the network

   ```
   [admin@router ~]$ sudo service network start
   ```
3. Setup hostapd

   Set the value of **/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf** to:

   ```
   #
   # For more information:
   #
   # https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd
   # https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf
   #

   # Wireless Interface
   interface=wls4
   driver=nl80211

   # Wireless Environment
   ssid=[router_ssid_here]
   hw_mode=g
   channel=1

   # Authentication and Encryption
   macaddr_acl=0
   auth_algs=1
   ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
   wpa=2
   wpa_passphrase=[ap_password_here]
   wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
   wpa_pairwise=TKIP
   rsn_pairwise=CCMP

   # Country
   country_code=US
   ieee80211d=1

   # IEEE 802.11ac (req hw_mode=a)
   # ieee80211ac=1

   # IEEE 802.11n
   ieee80211n=1

   # WMM
   wmm_enabled=1
   ```
4. Create a systemd service to add **wls4** to the bridge **br0** and launch hostapd. I did this for the following reasons:

   - **wls4** would sporadically drop from bridge **br0** when I added the bridge declaration in hostapd.conf
   - Before hostapd can successfully launch, I first needed to call `rfkill unblock wlan`
5. Create **/root/launch_hostapd.sh** (must be done as root)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # Set 4addr on wifi adapter
   iw dev wls4 set 4addr on

   # Add wifi adapter to bridge br0
   ip link set wls4 master br0

   # Unblock wlan
   rfkill unblock wlan

   # Launch hostapd
   systemctl start hostapd
   ```
6. Make **/root/launch_hostapd.sh** executable

   ```
   [admin@router ~]$ sudo chmod +x /root/launch_hostapd.sh
   ```
7. Create **/etc/systemd/system/launch_hostapd.service** (must be done as root)

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Runs "rfkill unblock wlan" and then launches hostapd
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   Type=simple
   ExecStart=/root/launch_hostapd.sh
   TimeoutStartSec=0

   [Install]
   WantedBy=default.target
   ```
8. Reload systemctl daemon

   ```
   [admin@router ~]$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
9. Enable/start launch_hostpad service

   ```
   [admin@router ~]$ sudo systemctl enable launch_hostapd
   [admin@router ~]$ sudo systemctl start launch_hostapd
   ```

### Conclusion

I hope this helps anyone else who may want to bridge their LAN and WLAN interfaces in the attempt to host an AP via hostapd.